# Would cooling matter and antimatter to as close to Absolute Zero as possible allow them to coexist?

Tags: antimatter, bose-einstein-condensate, cryogenics, positronium

I was reading about Bose-Einstein condensates and how they affect matter and energy, and I wondered if "draining" that amount of energy from an atom of hydrogen and positronium would potentially allow you to form H2 gas out of the two types of atoms.

Comment: @Countto10 There is at least 1K which is far many to have any BEC effect. In the BEC, the actual position of its particles is unknown. How does it affect the annihillation cross-sections? I don't have any idea, but I think it is not trivial.

Comment: @peterh accepted re the temperature. No offence to the OP, but either I misread the question (probably) or it is different now (as the annihilation reference is now gone), which was what my comment was about.

Comment: @Countto10 Ok ok. I've thought a little bit on it and now I think it wouldn't have a significant effect to the annihillation cross-section. But I am very far to say it for sure. What do you think?

Comment: script8man Nice question! A resolute NO for free electrons and positrons respectively protons and antiprotons. In my understanding because their electric fields don't disappear this pairs will annihilate perfectly. A hesitant YES in the case the electric dipole moments of the hydrogen and positronium disappear close to Absolute zero. This conviction is based on my elaboration about [Complex one-dimensional structures of space](https://www.academia.edu/19657550/Complex_one-dimensional_structures_of_space), especially the end of chapter "5.2 Dynamics of the electric field of the electron".